# Dojo query based on 2 attributes values

Tags: dojo

I have a webpage with 2 iframes having the same id (yes, that is the problem but I do not make the code, only using it), but with different style. So I would like to query (using dojo) the iframe having given id (to complicate the thing, id includes dots) AND given style (the one with style="").
I have tried many different queries but none work.

Please help !!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/KcbdY/4/)

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe.1" style="background-color:red">
    iframe1
</iframe>

<iframe id="iframe.1" style="">
    iframe2
</iframe>
```

JS:

```
var query1 = dojo.query('iframe[id="iframe.1"][style="background-color:red"]');
var query2 = dojo.query('iframe[id="iframe.1"][style=""]');
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work. We have rolled back to a previous version so I will not be able to test it right now. But, I will keep your answer for future usage.